# Dragonfly question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dragonfly-gem

I tried switching from gem rails 3.0.0.rc to rails 3.0.0 in my Gemfile recently and when doing so I got a problem with Dragonfly when starting the server. The error message says:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Dragonfly::Config::HerokuRailsImages (NameError)
```

from /Users/erikostling/Spatziba/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb:4

Switching back to RC doesn't help. Does anyone have an idea on what is wrong?

My dragonfly.rb looks like this:

```
require "dragonfly"
app = Dragonfly::App[:images]
app.configure_with(Dragonfly::Config::HerokuRailsImages, "static.my-app-domain.com")
app.parameters.default_format = :jpg
Dragonfly.active_record_macro(:image, app)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

E

Comment: Which dragonfly version you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to follow this [Rails 3 installation instructions](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Rails3.html).

Comment: Thank you! It seems when I did an bundle update my Dragonfly gem updated to a much more recent version of Dragonfly hence the errors.